# How to send an array of pointers to arrays in C MPI

Tags: c, multiprocessing, mpi

So let's say I'm using MPI and I want to be able to send a number of rows of a matrix of integers from the main process to other processes. It's relatively easy to do so, like this:

```
MPI_Send(&matrix[start_row][0], amount_of_cells, MPI_INT, target_process, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Now let's say that in our matrix, instead of each cell holding an integer, each cell holds a **reference to an integer array of size 2**. How could we send a number of rows of the new matrix to subprocesses?

I was thinking of doing the same thing as the code above but doubling the amount_of_cells variable because each cell holds a reference to an integer array of size 2. However, it doesn't seem to work, I'm at a bit of a loss here.

Any tips or advice on how to approach this would be helpful?

Old matrix:

```
_________
| 1 | 2 |
--------
| 3 | 4 |
_________
```

New matrix:

```
___________________

| [1, 0] | [2, 0] |
--------------------
| [3, 0] | [4, 0] |
___________________
```

So instead of holding integers, each cell holds a reference to an array of size 2 of integers created using `malloc()`. How could I send rows of this new matrix to subprocesses?

I was considering defining my own MPI datatype which could be a place to start.

Comment: Your best option is to change how you allocate your 2D arrays, and allocate them in contiguous memory. If this is not an option, then you can define your own datatype.

Comment: Yeah this is what I was thinking

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code,To send an array of pointers to arrays in C MPI

```
#include <mpi.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 

#define n 10 

int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }; 

int a2[1000]; 

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{ 

    int pid, np, 
        elements_per_process, 
        n_elements_recieved; 

    MPI_Status status; 

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv); 

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &pid); 
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &np); 

    if (pid == 0) { 
        int index, i; 
        elements_per_process = n / np; 

        if (np > 1) { 
            for (i = 1; i < np - 1; i++) { 
                index = i * elements_per_process; 

                MPI_Send(&elements_per_process, 
                        1, MPI_INT, i, 0, 
                        MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
                MPI_Send(&a[index], 
                        elements_per_process, 
                        MPI_INT, i, 0, 
                        MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
            } 

            index = i * elements_per_process; 
            int elements_left = n - index; 

            MPI_Send(&elements_left, 
                    1, MPI_INT, 
                    i, 0, 
                    MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
            MPI_Send(&a[index], 
                    elements_left, 
                    MPI_INT, i, 0, 
                    MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
        } 

        int sum = 0; 
        for (i = 0; i < elements_per_process; i++) 
            sum += a[i]; 

        int tmp; 
        for (i = 1; i < np; i++) { 
            MPI_Recv(&tmp, 1, MPI_INT, 
                    MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 0, 
                    MPI_COMM_WORLD, 
                    &status); 
            int sender = status.MPI_SOURCE; 

            sum += tmp; 
        } 

    printf("Sum of array is : %d\n", sum); 
    } 
    else { 
        MPI_Recv(&n_elements_recieved, 
                1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, 
                MPI_COMM_WORLD, 
                &status); 

        MPI_Recv(&a2, n_elements_recieved, 
                MPI_INT, 0, 0, 
                MPI_COMM_WORLD, 
                &status); 

        int partial_sum = 0; 
        for (int i = 0; i < n_elements_recieved; i++) 
            partial_sum += a2[i]; 

        MPI_Send(&partial_sum, 1, MPI_INT, 
                0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
    } 

    MPI_Finalize(); 

    return 0; 
}
```

I hope this code will be usefull.
Thank you.

Comment: I am afraid the intent is to send a jagged array in one shot.